# how could I handle an iterative naming system for this?

Tags: format, sas, naming

I have a dataset of this kind, this dataset contains some missing values 
(I'm representing them with X).

```
ID  VA  VB  ... Vn      |       ID  VA  VB  ... Vn  |   
1   a1  b1  ... n1      |       1   a1  X   ... n1  |
2   a2  b2  ... n2      |===    2   X   b2  ... X   |
3   a3  b3  ... n3      |===    3   a3  b3  ... n3  |
..................      |       ..................  |
N   aN  bN  ... nN      |       N   X   bN  ... nN  |
```

I want to add observations by ID using only one variable column, I will call
that variable VAR: something like an inverted proc format by ID; var VAR;.

```
ID  VAR
1   a1
..
1   n1 
2   b2
..
3   a3
3   b3
..
3   n3
..
N   bN
..  
N   nN
```

so I tried to split OLDdataset in different datasets (NEWa NEWb ...NEWn) where,
in each dataset we have all the not-missing observations stored in a column called
VAR.
Then I will merge NEWa NEWb ... NEWn in NEWdataset and I will apply a proc sort for
restoring the order by ID.

The problem arised when I realized that "n" is not known prior the analysis 'cause I
want to setup a generalized code that won't work for only one dataset, and VA VB VN
are the result of a proc format step.

If n is knows I would use something like this:

```
data NEWa NEWb NEWc;
set OLDdataset;
array try[3] VA VB VC ;
if try[1] ne '.' then output NEWa;
if try[1] ne '.' then output NEWb;
if try[1] ne '.' then output NEWc;
run;
```

But now i need some iterative naming system that maybe could sounds like:

```
data NEW_i;                     <-------- "i" must be assigned
set OLDdataset;
array try[*] V: ;
do i=1 dim(try);
if try[i] ne '.' then output NEW_i; <---- "i" must be assigned
run;
```

Hope this sounds clear.
Any hints?
Thanks.

Comment: A clarification: are the categories in each var are always distinct from each other? IOW: Can you have the same value for two different variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a proc transpose instead, you can delete the missing in a second step or add a where clause to the out data set. If you want to create subsets after that based on ID separate them out in a data step.

```
*generate sample data;
data have;
array V(20) v1-v20;
do ID=1 to 10;
    do i=1 to 20;
    v(i)=rand('normal', 0, 1);
    if v(i) < -2 then v(i)=.;
    end;
    output;
end;
drop i;
run;

*Flip data;
proc transpose data=have out=want(where=(var1 ne .)) prefix=Var;
    by id;
run;

*Separate into different data sets;
data _null_;
    set want;
    by id;
    call execute(catt("data var", id, "; set want; where id=", id, ";run;"));
run;
```

Comment: dear @Reese this is a great try, thanks for your help.
I'm not hiding that I'm pretty new with SAS environment and never heard about call execute() before. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the scenario correctly you are dealing with **numeric** variables, so on that basis you might not necessarily have to split the data by variable into different data sets, as you should be able to use the `nmiss()` function which returns the number of missing numeric values, e.g. in a subsetting if:

```
data newdataset;
  set olddataset;
  if nmiss(&varlist)=0;
run;
```

where `&varlist` could be created just before using olddataset in the above data step (as you said the number of variables can be dynamic) using:

```
/* note literals are case sensitive */
proc sql noprint;
  select name into :varlist separated by ','
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK'
    and memname='OLDDATASET'
    /* use following if you also have non-numeric variables */
    /* and type='num' */
  ;
quit;
```

You can use the following to see the contents of `&varlist`:

```
%put varlist=&varlist;
```

or even use the following option before the macro variable is referenced:

```
options symbolgen;
```

Comment: dear @Amir special thanks for the try!
anyway I'm pretty sure that this won't work because of this:
if nmiss(&varlist)=0;
all my column will return 0, because they all have at least a missing value :)
also, I'm working with character variables (categorical multilevel), and I'm so sorry for not having specified that in the text.